# Capture groups in Python regex issue

Tags: python, regex, nested

I'm searching for a string `Number of copies:` in a text file and once it's found, I want to print the digits associated with it, so I'm searching for, `(\sNumber of copies: (\d{1,2}))` and I want to return `(\d{1,2})`. I've been researching nested groups in REGEX, but I don't have the syntax down for it in Python. Any help would be appreciated.

```
zDiscs = re.search(r'(\sNumber of copies: (\d{1,2}))', fi2Content, re.M|re.I)
print(zDiscs.group(1))
```

Here what the line I'm looking for in a text file looks like:

```
12/13/2013 08:11:25  Number of Discs in Set: 2 - Number of copies: 2
```

My desired output would just be `2` and `2` because I'm looking for the number that follows the text.

`fi2Content` represent a whole text file read by Python.

I can `print(zDiscs)` but I can't `print(zDiscs.group(2))`. Why?

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

when I try to `print(zDiscs.group(2))`

Here's my whole script if that helps troubleshooting

```
fo = open('outputFile', 'w')
fo.write("Col1|Col2|Col3\n")
# 1.walk around directory and find lastjob.txt file in one of folders
rootDir = "C:\\Users\bob\Desktop\Path Parsing Project"
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
for filename in files:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if filename=="text.txt":
        print(fullpath)
        # 2.open file. read from file
        fi2 = open(fullpath, 'r')
        fi2Content = fi2.read()
        zDiscs = re.search(r'(\sNumber of copies: (\d{1,2}))', fi2Content, re.M|re.I)
        print(zDiscs.group(2)) #This is where the error occurs!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: the group 1 is all of your regex , for that your need `group(2)` also can you add a sample input?

Comment: @Kasra with `zDiscs.group(2)` I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: Its because of that your regex doesn't matched anything!! can you add a sample input and a desire output?

Comment: @Kasra I added the input and desired output to my question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be looking for:

```
import re
zDiscs = re.search(r'(\sNumber of copies: (\d{1,2}))', " 12/13/2013 08:11:25  Number of Discs in Set: 2 - Number of copies: 2", re.I)
print(zDiscs.group(2))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/hQqIYB)

Output: `54`

Mind that `re.M` is redundant in your regex as you do not have anchors `^` and `$` in your pattern (only their behavior is impacted by that option).

If you use `(\sNumber of copies: (\d{1,2}))`, there are 2 capturing groups, and the number will be in group 2.

If the file you search for the expression does not contain that text, and you want to skip it, check if you obtained a match object:

```
zDiscs = re.search(r'(\sNumber of copies: (\d{1,2}))', fi2Content, re.I)
if zDiscs:
    print(zDiscs.group(2))
```

Comment: I get the folowing error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` when I use `zDiscs.group(1)`. After researching, I tried this solution, and it didn't work even though this is how I though it would work. I am confused.

Comment: This means you do not have a match. What is your input string?

Comment: I ran your 3 lines of code, it worked. However, it doesn't work in my script. Still determining why.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with `fi2Content`.

Comment: `fi2content` is a huge text file with thousands of strings like the one above. The string are seperated by a `/n`

Comment: Try using a different approach: read this file line by line, and apply a compiled regex to each line.

Comment: For this particular operation, I can't do it as a read line by line. I want to do it before I read line by line, so I open the whole text file first for this fetching of data, then, I'll read line by line for fetching of other data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83151/discussion-between-phorsespec-and-stribizhev).